# How to do something after 2 days in django like deleting an object of a model

Tags: django, django-models

This is a model for all assignment taken by any user. How can I delete a particular instance of this when the user hasn't submitted his assignment in two days. After submission user data is saved in subassignment model.

```
class UserAssignment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment)
    time_taken = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    submitted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank = True)


class SubAssignment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment)
    time_submitted =models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `pip install django-celery==3.2.2`
2. add `'djcelery'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`
3. add task to check all UserAssignment everyday in 1 am:

tasks.py:

```
from celery import task
from .models import *

@task
def check_user_assignment():
    for user_assignment in UserAssignment.objects.all():
        # check all every day,if need to delete,then delete it
        pass
```

4. add this task to

settings.py

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://root:root@localhost:5672/'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'check_user_assignment_everyday': {
        'task': 'user.tasks.check_user_assignment',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=1),
        'args': (),
    },
}
```

5. run celery :
   input in terminal

   `python manage.py celery beat -l info`

   `python manage.py celery worker -E -l info`

Comment: will it timeout ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use timedelta:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Some of your code
# Let's create 2 day threshold
threshold = datetime.now()-timedelta(days=2)
missed_assignment =  UserAssignment.objects.filter(user=user,
                                                   time_taken__gte=threshold)
missed_assignment.delete()


missed_subassignment = SubAssignment.objects.filter(user=user,                    
                                                    time_submitted__gte=threshold)

missed_subassignment.delete()
```

Note that `time_submitted__gte` means "time passed is more than or at threshold".
If you do not actually run code, you may use rq worker -https://github.com/rq/django-rq or just a cron tab that periodically checks.